# Arabic letters considered as symbols in regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am using this regex to trim all symbols but when typing arabic letters like " أ , ع "
regex treat these as symbols .

**Example**

print(_trimSearchName("  ba,.[nana"));

result is banana

print(_trimSearchName("موز"));

result is

So how to override all arabic letters ?

```
 String _trimSearchName(String searchName){
return searchName.trim().replaceFirst(RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'), '');}
```

Comment: Can you make an example which shows the input and the expected output? Not all (including myself) are expert in arabic letters. :)

Comment: I have just added it . @julemand101

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have an example where we actually remove some stuff instead of just returning the same as we input? Also, I want to know the expected result. Not more example of your problem. :)

Comment: yes , sorry I edited it .

Comment: Can you try: `String _trimSearchName(String searchName) =>
    searchName.trim().replaceFirst(RegExp(r'[^\p{L}\s]+', unicode: true), '');`

Comment: Great, I have added an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
void main() {
  print(_trimSearchName(" ba,.[nana")); // banana
  print(_trimSearchName("موز")); // موز
}

String _trimSearchName(String searchName) =>
    searchName.trim().replaceFirst(RegExp(r'[^\p{L}\s]+', unicode: true), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-8 notation range: `[^\u0621-\u064A\w\s]`

Or: `[^\p{Arabic}\w\s]`